# How do I remove a row containing NA if NAs are allowed before a person enters a sample?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am working with a panel data set containing years 1-12. If a person enters in year 4, their values for `Weight` will be `NA` before year 4. I only want to remove this row (person) if after year 4 there are any `NA` values.

```
data : Weight_Y1   W_Y2    W_Y3    W_Y4    W_Y5    W_Y6    W_Y7    W_8     W_9 ...
Ind_1    NA        NA       NA     82kg   81       83      84      NA      86
```

This individual should be deleted. So, as soon as an observation is registered as active in the survey `NA` is not allowed for following observations. Besides `Weight` I also have other variables (columns) so I need to do this on specific columns as well.

Comment: say you have dataframe `x <- data.frame(x = 1:10)` Now to share it with others do `dput(x)` in your R console and hit enter. Copy the output and use it to share it with others. So for this example, you get `structure(list(x = 1:10), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))`. So now, we copy it and do `x <- structure(list(x = 1:10), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))` in our console and we have the same data `x` as you. It is better way to share data.

Comment: aahh okay, we go through R. I thought maybe Stack Overflow could translate it directly. I will btw be asking a question soon about the `melt` command from the `reshape2` package. I need to add a time variable to my dataset and reshape it from  wide to long format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `apply` using `MARGIN = 1` row-wise

```
#Select columns based on pattern in the weight column
cols <- grep("^W", names(df))

#Select rows only if there is no NA after the first non-NA is encountered.
df[!apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) any(which(is.na(x)) > which.max(!is.na(x)))), ]

#   data W_Y1 W_Y2 W_Y3 W_Y4 W_Y5 W_Y6 W_Y7 W_8 W_9
#2 Ind_2   NA   NA   NA   82   81   83   84  65  86
```

---

Using similar logic but with `mapply` and `max.col`

```
df[mapply(function(x, y) !any(which(is.na(df[x, cols])) > y),1:nrow(df),
       max.col(!is.na(df[cols]), ties.method = "first")), ]
```

Using `max.col` we find the index of first non-NA value in the `cols` and then check if there is any value in that row which has `NA` after that index.

**data**

I added some rows to make a better example

```
df <- structure(list(data = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Ind_1", "Ind_2", 
"Ind_3", "Ind_4"), class = "factor"), W_Y1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA
), W_Y2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 23L), W_Y3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), W_Y4 = c(82L, 
82L, 82L, 82L), W_Y5 = c(81L, 81L, 81L, 81L), W_Y6 = c(83L, 83L, 
83L, 83L), W_Y7 = c(84L, 84L, NA, 84L), W_8 = c(NA, 65L, NA, 
12L), W_9 = c(86L, 86L, 86L, 86L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df
#   data W_Y1 W_Y2 W_Y3 W_Y4 W_Y5 W_Y6 W_Y7 W_8 W_9
#1 Ind_1   NA   NA   NA   82   81   83   84  NA  86
#2 Ind_2   NA   NA   NA   82   81   83   84  65  86
#3 Ind_3   NA   NA   NA   82   81   83   NA  NA  86
#4 Ind_4   NA   23   NA   82   81   83   84  12  86
```

Comment: I have two questions. What do you mean with `MARGIN = 1`? Is that command you use? I don't understand

I am also confused about the first line using `grep`:
what does the "`^`" infront of the variable name mean? My variables are fx `r1srhlt - r12rsrhlt`, and `r1diabets - r12diabetes`. Would I then write:
`colsdiabetes <--grep("^diab", names(df))`

Comment: @EmilKrabbe "^" means starts with so if all the weight columns start with r, do `cols <- grep("^r", names(df))`

Comment: all my variables are named "r1 - r12" though. So for example I have r1height - r12height but also r1weight-r12weight and r1bmi - r12 bmi. what can I do then? Is there an *ends with* command? all my endings are specific to the variables

Comment: so which variable do you want to select as weight then? In my example I have `W_Y1`,  `W_Y2` as weights. Which one do want to consider? r1height , r2height ones? or the one with weight or the one with BMI or all of them??

Comment: @EmilKrabbe so for height first do `cols <- grep("height$", names(df))` and then do `df[!apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) any(which(is.na(x)) > which.max(!is.na(x)))), ]` and then for weight just change `cols` to `cols <- grep("weight$", names(df))` and use the same `apply` function.

Comment: now you changed the "^" to a "$". Does that mean you look at the last part of the word?

Comment: @EmilKrabbe yes. because in your example you had weight columns as `W_Y2`, `W_Y3` etc so in my answer I selected columns which starts with "W" but now in the comment you mentioned that you have columns called `r1height`, `r2height` etc. so I now select columns which end with "height".

Comment: I see. Still one minor problem:
1) when I run the first command (`grep`) I get this 
             > cols
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

I would have expected R to give me the 10 columns.. but instead it just gives me a vector of the numbers 1-10. This seems very odd to me.

Comment: No those are column numbers which have "height" at the end. When we use `apply`, we select only those columns by doing `df[cols]` so need to use `grepl`.

Comment: I see, the grepl command does something different. Thanks for everything it works now

Answer (score 1):

`tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(year, weight, W_Y1:W_Y12) %>%
  group_by(data) %>%
  mutate(
    cond = max(which(is.na(weight))) < min(which(!is.na(weight))),
    year = year %>% reorder(str_extract(year, '\\d+') %>% as.numeric()) # just to keep right order of columns after 'spread()'
  ) %>%
  spread(year, weight) %>%
  filter(cond)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check for NAs using `base::rle` then filter when NAs happened one or less

```
flag<-apply(df[,grepl('^W',names(df))],1, function(x) sum(rle(is.na(x))$values))
df[df$flag<=1,]
```